# How can add my javaScript total function with google spreadsheet, I'm not able select the range in one sheet where I need to get the result

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can add number in google spreadsheet with formula but I want to do it without formula, I can create total function with other editor and works fine but I cannot get it going with google spreadsheet.

```
  function calculateSum(){

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet=ss.getSheets()[0];

  var cell=sheet.getRange("B22");

  cell.setFormula("=sum(B17:B21)");    
}
```

javaScript  Code is Below:-

```
function addNumbers(a,b,c){
     var sum=a+b+c;
     return sum;
  }
var result=addNumbers(2,3,4);
document.write(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
function addRange() {
  var myVals = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange("A1:A11").getValues();  
  var answer = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < myVals.length; i++) {
    answer = answer + myVals[i][0];
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange("A12").getCell(1,1).setValue(answer);
}
```

To do multiple columns try this:

```
function addRange() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
    var cellValues = sheet.getRange("A1:C12").getValues();   // 2D array
    var columnCount = cellValues[0].length;
    var rowCount = cellValues.length;
    var answer = 0;

    for (var row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
        for (var column = 0; column < columnCount; column++) {
            answer = answer + cellValues[row][column];
        }
    }
    sheet.getRange("D12").getCell(1, 1).setValue(answer);
}
```

Comment: Hey Nancy thank you for you help!! It works fine with 1  row and 1 column but when I change the range for multiple rows and columns it does not work gets an error out of range , could you suggest ?

Comment: Amit - to accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. Thanks.